# CURL following with modified header

Tags: apache, curl, httpd.conf

i need to check a redirect, but i've twoo rules under that: first to pass to https, second the specific. If i test with https it works perfect, but if i try under http, as it makes first a redirect to https, it loose the headers where i modify the ip:

This is how i test that:

> curl -LIk -H 'Header: test.com' 'https://192.168.139.24/test-app' |
>   grep HTTP
>
> curl -LIk -H 'Header: test.com' 'http://192.168.139.24/test-app' |
>   grep HTTP

The first one works, but the second one dont, because i've a rule into the httpd.conf like:

```
    RewriteCond     %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
    RewriteRule     .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

So, as i've passed the host, but i've asked for that host in a specific IP, it rewrites to a URL with the host, but forget the IP asked, this way it sends me to the other node...

Have you any idea to solve that and can get a test by node?

Comment: Don't see any difference from `curl` command first and the second one ?

Comment: Sorry, rewrited. The difference is that the first one goes with http and the second one with https. So as i've a rule into the httpd.conf to redirect http to https and apache makes first the rules into the httpd.conf against .htaccess, it changes me the fake host, and goes with the host modificated in real!.

Comment: You probably wanted to use `Host: test.com` instead of `Header: test.com`?